# Listener MesiboGroupCall_OnVideoSourceChanged is not called when changing video source

Tags: javascript, mesibo

In my application I need to know when a user switches to show his screen instead of camera, both the local user and for other users. When I change to showing the user's screen, MesiboGroupcall_OnVideoSourceChanged is not called. The only listeners that are called is MesiboGroupcall_OnVideo and MesiboGroupcall_OnAudio for the local participant, and no listeners for remote participants.

Inspecting the participant through the console shows that the listener have indeed been set to be my desired function,

```
MesiboGroupcall_OnVideoSourceChanged: (newVideoSource, oldVideoSource) => {
    console.log("MesiboGroupcall_onVideoSourceChanged: newVideoSource:", newVideoSource, "- oldVideoSource:", oldVideoSource);
}
```

but it won't run. Do anyone have any tips on getting this to work?

From what I can decipher reading mesibo.js, MesiboGroupCall_OnVideoSourceChanged is the only listener that is referenced only twice, when it is declared and when it is set in the call method. It seems like it isn't called elsewhere, for instance I would expect it to be called in to methods that change the video source like .setVideoSource(). I also find no reference to MesiboGroupcall_OnVideoSourceChanged in the source code for the live demo web application, which leads me to suspect that it might not be implemented yet or work correctly. If any mesibo devs read this, maybe they can clarify.

It would also be useful to get information back locally when the user allows or disallows the screensharing, are there any way of doing this with mesibo? I see other video conference providers do this through promises, but I have a hard time seeing if anything similar is available for mesibo, without having more documentation on the mesibo interface.
I thought maybe I can listen for it through the DOM, but haven't looked into doing that yet. If anyone has any experience or thoughts on this, that would also be great.

Comment: @Herald MesiboGroupcall_OnVideoSourceChanged is currently available for mesibo Android and iOS only. It should be available on JS too. Currently, the JS API uses the older API Mesibo_OnLocalMedia. Can you please file a ticket here, https://mesibo.com/help

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Does this mean I should use the documentation at https://mesibo.com/documentation/conferencing/, rather than https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/conferencing/ when I build my application?

Comment: You can use Mesibo_OnLocalMedia till it is fixed but not recommended to use other old APIs. Although mesobo.js supports both old and new APIs at this moment, the old APIs and the old documentation will be removed soon. Old APIs will also be not supported by on-premise. Hence, If you find any issues, raise a ticket, and can be fixed rather than using old APIs. You will also find updated Android, iOS, and Web apps on GitHub next week.